# Truncate a tweet while leaving links intact using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter, tweets

I'm using [Tweet](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) to echo tweets and I want to truncate the tweet to a character limit but possibly keep the links intact (if they get truncated). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you are truncating to fit a set char length, how do you plan to "keep" URLs if they spill over the char limit?

Comment: I think that's what he is asking...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm trying to see if I can truncate a string while keeping the <a> tags intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This plugin](http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/02/jquery-html-truncate) did it for me, here's what my tweet function looks like:

```
$("#tweet").tweet({
        username:'adamzwakk',
        count: 1,
        template: "{text} {time}"
    }).bind("loaded", function() {
        var ul = $(this).find(".tweet_list");
        ul.find('.tweet_text').truncate({
            max_length: 100,
            more: '',
            less: ''
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing some searching for those links within the tweet (grab everything between `<a>` and `</a>`), extract them, truncate your tweet to "X characters MINUS ExtractedLinkLength" sort of thing, then add the link to the end of your truncated tweet. Not sure of the code but that should work as a theory.